# Java lib between ajax and database

Tags: java, ajax, database, geoserver, cql

**Background:**

I'm using geoserver and openlayers to develop a gis webapp.
Now I find myself in the need to retrieve some data from the database to make statistics and other stuff (some not gis related).

I'm currently using an old lib from my company but no one knows where the source is and there is no documentation (no comments...).

The current lib I'm using has a configuration file on the server side where I define the queries. Then from the javascript I invoke the service with the query name and the parameters.

There is of course the WFS service, but some of the requests I need to do are not gis related and it will not be a good practice to use WFS for that.

**Question:**

Is there a java lib I can use "out of the box" to make such requests from ajax to the database? (It would be better if it supports CQL and geo data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is [GeoTools](http://www.geotools.org/). GeoTools is a mapping lib, but it has many functions for [spatial querys](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/tutorials/geometry/geometrycrs.html#geometry) and also supports [CQL](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/tutorials/filter/query.html#id1)